# ckeditor automatically reformats my text in a way where I dont fully see the pattern

Tags: ckeditor

ckeditor automatically reformats my text in a way where I dont fully see the pattern

Below is the raw html code I insert in the editor through the source view. It should iterate an list if orderlines.
The users can edit their own mail templates, which are persisted in database and retrieved and populated with data through freemarker other places around the code. This question is somehow related to this one:
    [ckeditor escapes all text - how can I prevent it from doing so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949938/ckeditor-espace-all-text-how-can-i-prevent-it-from-doing-so/6949964#6949964)

okay, so this is the text I enter i the source view part of the ckeditor:

```
<p>Hei customer with name ${Customer.name}</p>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Antall</th>
    <th>Kasse</th>
    <th>Leveringsdat</th>
    <th>Hyppighet</th>
    <th>Leveringsstart</th>
    <th>Pris ordrelinje</th>
  </tr>
  &lt;#list Order.orderLines as ol&gt;
  <tr>
    <td>${ol.number}</td>
    <td>${ol.box.name}</td>
    <td>${Order.weekday}</td>
    <td>${Order.frequence}</td>
    <td>${Order.startdate}</td>
    <td>Pris senere</td>
  </tr>
  &lt;/#list&gt;
</table>
```

And when I change the view from "source" to "html" again, and then back, the editor has transformed the code to this:

```
<p>
    Hei customer with name ${Customer.name}</p>
<p>
    &lt;#list Order.orderLines as ol&gt; &lt;/#list&gt;</p>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Antall</th>
            <th>
                Kasse</th>
            <th>
                Leveringsdat</th>
            <th>
                Hyppighet</th>
            <th>
                Leveringsstart</th>
            <th>
                Pris ordrelinje</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                ${ol.number}</td>
            <td>
                ${ol.box.name}</td>
            <td>
                ${Order.weekday}</td>
            <td>
                ${Order.frequence}</td>
            <td>
                ${Order.startdate}</td>
            <td>
                Pris senere</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

It has moved this part "<#list Order.orderLines as ol> </#list>" out of the table and up on the top of the HTML. I can understand that the editor somehow tries to be smart and see "aha, that is not valid html, I will manipulate it and do it correct", so I have two questions:

1) is it possible to configure somehow that the editor should not manipulated html Iv entered 
2) anyone has a good link a documentation describe exactly which rules are applied when the editor those these kind of manipulation?

Comment: Did you get solution for it. I am facing the same issue